# Carriage Return in Notepad

Tags: excel, carriage-return, notepad

I have between 1-2 thousand notepad files that I need to add a new line to. I have an excel macro that can automatically find and replace text in notepad files, which I can use to add in the text I need. The excel macro has one cell where the user types the text to be found, and another where the user types the text that will replace that text. The problem is, I need to replace one line with two, and putting in a linebreak in the 'replace with' cell in excel (using alt-enter) does not put the text on a new line in notepad.
Interestingly, when I open the notepad file in Word, it does show up on a new line, with a carriage return between the two lines, but is still on the same line in notepad. Is there any way that I can use the excel macro to add the carriage return to show up in notepad?

Comment: Post the macro you are currently using.....are you inserting a Chr(10) or Chr(13) or both?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will only put a line feed into the string.
Notepad does not understand the "UNIX" style of encoding, but more advanced programs do.

if you replace the line feed with a full DOS newline, you should find your problem goes away:

```
NewString=Replace(OldString,vbLf,vbCrLf)
```

*vbLf is the excel constant for the line feed.

vbCrLf is the excel constant for the DOS newline.*